# Google map show blank screen with Google logo in bottom

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources

My problem is that

> "While running my application i am getting blank Google Map with
>   Google Logo at bottom"

Comment: if that is the case don't you think that show compile time error?

Answer (score 2):

You have missed something related to `API_KEY` generating and using. Please re-check if you have generated `API_KEY` properly for your package name com.winthrop. You can refer steps [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/)